# Как присвоить значение переменной по умолчанию у switch в android studio?

Tags: java, android

Подскажите пожалуйста, как присвоить значение переменной по умолчанию в переключателе switch, чтобы переменная устанавливалась до клика на switch, например:

```
    switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                a = 2;
            } else {
                a = 1;
            }
        }
    });
```

В таком коде значение переменной a устанавливается только после клика на switch. А есть ли возможность установить значение переменной заранее, но не при инициализации переменной, а чтобы значение было взято именно из switch, не кликая на него?
Благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете проверить текущее состояние вашего `Switch` и в зависимости от состояния присвоить ему значение при инициализации самого `Switch`. Например так:

```
int a = switch.isChecked() ? 2 : 1;
```